# Hide/Show toggle echo results in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to toggle results i have echo'd out of table but i am having no luck.
I have tried the same code in HTML and it works perfectly.
Ive been working on this for a while now, and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

**What I've tired**

- Adding the javascript inside the php echo.
- Adding a counter to the id, to make it unique on loop
- Placing each line of the echo results in echo(""); tags.

adding a counter, to make the id unique on loop.

PHP

```
   $i = 1;
   while ($output = $fc_sel->fetch_assoc()) {
   $fc_run .= $output['Food_Cat_name'] . $output['Food_Cat_Desc'] . '<br>';
   $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] = $output['Food_Cat_name']; //echo out product name
   $_SESSION['Food_Cat_Desc'] = $output['Food_Cat_Desc']; //echo out product desc
 echo"

 <div id='first_product'>

 <button onclick='toggle_visibility('tog')'>Toggle</button>
  <div id='tog'>

        <div id='red_head'>
            <p id='menu_title' class ='hidden' onclick='toggle_visibility('tog')'>  Add your first menu item</p>
        </div>
        <h3 id='menu'>Menu Section</h3>

        <form name='first_prod' id='first_prod' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='testing.php' method='POST' accept-charset='utf-8' >               

            <label id='cat_label' name='cat_label'>Name</label>
            <input type='text' id='cat_name' name='cat_name' value=''>

            <label id='desc_label' name='desc_label'>Description</label>
            <input type='text' id='cat_desc' name='cat_desc' value=''>



        </form>


    </div>
    </div>

    ";  
    }
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 <script>
    //turn entire div into toggle
        function toggle_visibility(id) {

            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
                e.style.display = 'none';
            else
                e.style.display = 'block';
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: You are confusing java and javascript,even the tag description mentions it

Comment: @Mihai yes you are correct, i just noticed that. I have made the amendments

Comment: `'toggle_visibility('tog')'` : you need to escape char in the function like this : `'toggle_visibility(\'tog\')'`

Comment: @VincentG i forgot to mention i have also tired that.

Comment: Share you code with the loop code and the rendered HTML from browser get it like in chrome load page `Ctrl + u`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 it works perfectly in HTML, this i already know it is just when i try echo it out. it doesn't work. I will had my loop to my question now

Comment: I have worked it out have added my loop $i into the end of each id name. for example tog$i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes in `onclick='toggle_visibility('tog')'` are conflicting with the outer single quotes. So either escape them or use double quotes in either the outer pair or the inner pair.

Then in PHP, remove the `<?php  echo`. Just put the HTML in PHP. The `echo` only complicates things. If you need dynamic data in your HTML, just inject it at that place with `<?php ... ?>`. But so far I haven't seen any of that in your HTML: it is static.

Here is a working snippet, after having made that change in two places:

```js
//turn entire div into toggle
function toggle_visibility(id) {

  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id='first_product'>
  <button onclick="toggle_visibility('tog')">Toggle</button>
  <div id='tog'>
    <div id='red_head'>
      <p id='menu_title' class ='hidden' onclick="toggle_visibility('tog')">  Add your first menu item</p>
    </div>
    <h3 id='menu'>Menu Section</h3>
    <form name='first_prod' id='first_prod' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='testing.php' method='POST' accept-charset='utf-8' >               
      <label id='cat_label' name='cat_label'>Name</label>
      <input type='text' id='cat_name' name='cat_name' value=''>
      <label id='desc_label' name='desc_label'>Description</label>
      <input type='text' id='cat_desc' name='cat_desc' value=''>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit after modification of the question

The code in the question was extended so the HTML is produced in a loop now.

You should now take care to produce unique *id* values only. So you'll probably want to add `<?=$i?>` at several places, like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
// ....
$i = 1;
while ($output = $fc_sel->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fc_run .= $output['Food_Cat_name'] . $output['Food_Cat_Desc'] . '<br>';
    $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] = $output['Food_Cat_name'];
    $_SESSION['Food_Cat_Desc'] = $output['Food_Cat_Desc'];
?>

<div id='first_product<?=$i>'>

<button onclick="toggle_visibility('tog<?=$i>')">Toggle</button>
<div id='tog<?=$i>'>
    <div id='red_head<?=$i>'>
```

...etc. Note that the PHP was closed before the HTML output started. Do this, instead of a large `echo`. Then at the end of it, open PHP tag again to end the loop:

```
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there anyway of getting around the single quotes and double quotes thing? the reason i ask is because i can echoing out the data and in my echo i use a double quote, using a double quote with the echo tag conflicts with the echo's double quote. If that makes sense

Comment: Only use PHP `echo` at the place where you need it. Don't use it on a long section of HTML. HTML should just be put outside of `<?php ... ?>` in your PHP file.

Comment: This helped a lot. But i found it was the fact i didn't add $i to the end of tog

Comment: OK. Of course I could not have said anything about *$i*, because it was not in your original question. Now I have added a section about that.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah i didn't realise that was the problem. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

please modify your code

```
echo "

 <div id='first_product'>

 <button onclick='toggle_visibility(\"tog\")'>Toggle</button>
  <div id='tog'>

        <div id='red_head'>
            <p id='menu_title' class ='hidden' onclick='toggle_visibility(\"tog\")'>  Add your first menu item</p>
        </div>
        <h3 id='menu'>Menu Section</h3>

        <form name='first_prod' id='first_prod' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='testing.php' method='POST' accept-charset='utf-8' >               

            <label id='cat_label' name='cat_label'>Name</label>
            <input type='text' id='cat_name' name='cat_name' value=''>

            <label id='desc_label' name='desc_label'>Description</label>
            <input type='text' id='cat_desc' name='cat_desc' value=''>



        </form>


    </div>
    </div>

    "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button value='tog' onclick='toggle_visibility(this)'>Toggle</button>
```

Just use "this" and assign value to button its working

Comment: This doesn't work. The function `toggle_visibility` expects a string, and its purpose is not to hide the button you clicked on either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while($output = $fc_sel->fetch_assoc()){
  $fc_run .= $output['Food_Cat_name'] . $output['Food_Cat_Desc'] . '<br>';
  $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] = $output['Food_Cat_name']; //echo out product name
  $_SESSION['Food_Cat_Desc'] = $output['Food_Cat_Desc']; //echo out product desc
  ?>
  <div id="first_product<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <button onclick="javascript:toggle_visibility('tog<?php echo $i; ?>')">Toggle</button>
    <div id="tog<?php echo $i; ?>">
      <div id="red_head<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <p id="menu_title<?php echo $i; ?>" class ="hidden" onclick="toggle_visibility('tog<?php echo $i; ?>')">  Add your first menu item</p>
      </div>
      <h3 id="menu<?php echo $i; ?>">Menu Section</h3>
      <form name="first_prod" id="first_prod<?php echo $i; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testing.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label id="cat_label<?php echo $i; ?>" name="cat_label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="cat_name<?php echo $i; ?>" name="cat_name" value="">
        <label id="desc_label<?php echo $i; ?>" name="desc_label">Description</label>
        <input type="text" id="cat_desc<?php echo $i; ?>" name="cat_desc" value="">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
  $i++;
}
?>
```